# Autohotkey Button with loop

Tags: loops, user-interface, button, autohotkey

i have a question. I have create a few Buttons but when i start a button it dont start the loop. And how can i set a variable for a button that fits in %edelstein%
Thank you for help

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Force
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
SetBatchLines -1
^k::
Gui, Add, Button, x32 y29 w90 h40 , Diamand
Gui, Add, Button, x152 y29 w90 h40 , Flawless Diamand
Gui, Add, Button, x272 y29 w90 h40 , Perfekter Diamand
Gui, Show, w479 h379, Untitled GUI
InputBox, count,
Loop %count%
{
    ImageSearch, found_x, found_y, 0, 0, 1200, 1200, *100 %edelstein%.png
    if (!ErrorLevel)
    {
    Send, {Control down} 
    MouseClick, left, %found_x%, %found_y% 
    Send, {Control up} 
    
    }
```

I try it with different g Labels but it allways skip the Loop

Answer (score 0):

[**Documentation**](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/) is always your best friend.

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance, Force
SetWorkingDir, %A_ScriptDir%
SetBatchLines, -1

Gui, Add, Button, x32 y29 w90 h40   vDiamand            gOnButtonClick, Diamand
Gui, Add, Button, x152 y29 w90 h40  vFlawless_Diamand   gOnButtonClick, Flawless Diamand
Gui, Add, Button, x272 y29 w90 h40  vPerfekter_Diamand  gOnButtonClick, Perfekter Diamand
Gui, Show, w479 h379, Untitled GUI

edelstein := "ImageName"
Return

GuiClose:
ExitApp

OnButtonClick:
    Msgbox, % A_GuiControl
Return

^k::
    InputBox, count
    Loop, %count% {
        ImageSearch, found_x, found_y, 0, 0, 1200, 1200, *100 %edelstein%.png
        
        if (ErrorLevel = 2)
            MsgBox, 16,, Could not conduct the search.
        Else if (ErrorLevel = 1)
            MsgBox, 16,, Icon could not be found on the screen.
        Else {
            Send, {Control down} 
            MouseClick, left, %found_x%, %found_y% 
            Send, {Control up} 
        }
    }
Return
```